# Определенное слово + цифра php регулярка

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, парсер

```
$dannie = "Длина: 100 м
Длина 100 метров
Длина 100м";
```

Нужна регулярка которая будет находить определенное слово (в данном случае длина), и получать цифру идущую за ней, **и на этом поиск прекращала**, а не шла дальше и цепляла все остальные цифры. Почему то так не срабатывает. Почему не могу понять:

```
$str = preg_match_all("/([Длина:]+\d)/ui", $dannie, $out);
echo $dlina_result = implode(', ', $out[0]);
```

Пример: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b4efb8e5baba773d4c88e175d9ec8b105a5cd05d

Comment: `/([^Длина:]+\d)/ui`

Comment: какой результат должен быть 100 или 100,100,100 ?

Comment: результат должен быт 100. то есть значение одного поля. Дублирующие как пример мусорных данных

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте

```
$dannie = "Длина: 100 м
Длина 100 метров
Длина 100м";
if (preg_match_all('~Длина:\s*\K\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?~u', $dannie, $matches)) {
    echo implode(', ', $matches[0]);
}
```

[Пример работы кода онлайн](https://3v4l.org/HbYg3). См. также [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/HHVV6h/1).

**Подробности**

- `Длина:` - буквальный текст
- `\s*` - 0 и более пробельных символов
- `\K` - оператор, удаляющий весь найденный текст из текущего совпадения
- `\d+` - 1 и более цифр
- `(?:[.,]\d+)?` - 1 или 0 повторов последовательности:

  - `[.,]`  - точка или запятая
  - `\d+` - 1 и более цифр

Comment: за подробности отдельное спасибо, на этапе изучения - очень полезно!

Comment: кажется, вопрос решает. Спасибо! замечательно развернутый ответ. А еще была бы очень интересна вариация, где после цифры еще указывается слово, которое должно идти после. Например что бы получить значение из "Длина 100 метров"

Так находит два значения: preg_match_all('~Длина\s*\K\d+(?:[.,]\d+[метров])?~u'

Comment: @Amsterdam Зачем вы лепите всюду квадратные скобки? `[метров]` = `[рметов]` = `[рметво]` и т.д., это символьный класс, который находит один из символов, указанных в классе. `'~Длина:\s*\K\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?(?=\s*м(?:етров)?\b)~u'` - [демо](https://regex101.com/r/HHVV6h/2).

Comment: леплю, потому что очень слабо пока разбираюсь в теме. ошибаюсь и путаюсь. Ваш доп.пример превосходен, спасибо отдельное за него!

Comment: @Amsterdam Я всегда добавляю подробные объяснения шаблонов потому, что каждый символ что-то значит. Одна скобка - и ничего работать не будет. Будьте внимательны, пользуйтесь http://regex101.com, сразу увидете, если что-то пойдёт не так.

Comment: спасибо, возьму на вооружение! Не знал о таком до этой темы

Comment: сейчас задумался над такой штукой - возможно ли получить текст только при выполнении одного из условий? То есть Указать "длина + цифра + метров", и если хоть одно из слов имеется, то забираем значение?

Попробовал "длина*", полагая что * это 0 или больше, но видимо моя логика вообще далека от верной в регулярках

Comment: @Amsterdam `'~Длина:\s*\K\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?|\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?(?=\s*м?(?:етров)?\b)~u'`, [демо](https://regex101.com/r/EfRf6h/2)

Comment: понял суть. благодарности моей нет предела, спасибо!

Comment: обнаружил небольшую неточность. Уравнение почему то собирает любые цифры: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/879a0fa64b71615535a4bb76dcd8737a5aadc219

Comment: @Amsterdam Я забыл удалить знак вопроса после `м` (эта часть обязательна): `'~Длина:\s*\K\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?|\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?(?=\s*м(?:етров)?\b)~u'`

Comment: немного лирика, но поразительно, какой мощный инструмент регулярка в умелых руках. поражаюсь. Спасибо, теперь все прекрасно работает.

Comment: @Amsterdam Тоже лирика, но я поражаюсь количеству вопросов на эту тему (регулярных выражений) сегодня. Кажется, рекорд.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, что двоеточие относится к маске и число отделено пробелами, то так:

```
preg_match_all("/(?<=Длина:)\s*(\d+)/ui", $dannie, $out);
echo $out[0][0];
```

Comment: `(\d)` и будет браться только 1 символ числа?

Comment: @InDevX я предполагаю что автор имел в виду именно цифру а не число, хотя в наше время...

Comment: @InDevX да, Вы правы, подправил :(

Comment: @SergeySolodukhin автор предполагал именно число, да. не точно выразился, пардон

Comment: Если используется подмаска, тогда нет необходимости и в блоке предварительного просмотра.

Comment: ваш код все равно берет только один символ из числа http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/05028ec0b2d74cd1fc058a5746fdb27d064ad892

Comment: @Amsterdam забавно, на [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) всё работает.

Comment: вы внесли какие то правки? не могу понять, потому что результат тот же..

Comment: @Amsterdam в сандбоксе на экран выводися количество совпадений. я сам повелся :)

Answer (score 0):

Регулярка `длина\D*(\d+)/i`, брать первую группу:

```js
var s = `Длина: 100 м
Длина 100 метров
Длина 100м`

console.log(s.match(/длина\D*(\d+)/i)[1])
```